# C/C++ faster calls from array of functions

Tags: c++, performance

Dear all, 
I've a program in C++ that should be as fast as possible. 
In particular, there is a crucial part that works as follows:

There is a variable D ranging in [0,255], based on its value 
it calls the function whose pointer is stored in a array F (with 255 elements). 
i.e., F[D]  gives the pointer to the function to call. 
The functions are very simple, they execute few expressions or/and assignments (no cycles).

How can I do this faster?

I can replicate the code in the functions. I do not need features of functions call (I'm using them since it was simpler way to do). 
My goal is that of removing the inefficiencies due to calls of functions.

I consider to use Switch/case. 
The code of each case is the code of the corresponding function. 
Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: it seems unlikely that this would make any difference to performance. Have you done any profiling?

Comment: @David: To me it seems really likely that inlining busy, small functions will make a difference to performance.

Comment: @kotlinski: The problem is that you can't really inline them. Sure, you can inline them in the context of the switch, but that's still not inline, because the switch isn't going to be inlined.

Comment: @Billy: If the switch is only used in one place in a program (e.g. inside a loop) it may very well be inlined.

Comment: Even if the switch is used in several spots, you *could* wrap a `__forceinline` version in a normal function and use the fast,big version in the critical loop and the slower, smaller version everywhere else.  However, beware premature optimization...

Comment: @OP: Your scenario is uncommon - can you explain why you have 256 functions like this?  Perhaps a different setup of the algorithm can avoid this problem entirely?

Answer (score 3):

- Convert it to a `switch`
- Make sure the tiny functions can be inlined (how to do this is compiler dependant - but explicitly marking them `inline` and placing them in the compilation unit is a good bet)
- Finally, you might try profile-guided optimizations if (as seems quite possible) your switch statement calls the branches in a non-uniform fashion.

The aim is to avoid function-call overhead and have the compiler reorder the switch statement to reduce the number of branches typically encountered.

***Edit:*** since there's some skeptical voices as to how much this helps; I gave it a shot.  In the following program, the function-pointer loop needs 1.07 seconds, and the inlined switch statement takes 0.79 seconds on my machine - YMMV:

```
template<unsigned n0,unsigned n> struct F { static inline unsigned func(unsigned val); };

template<unsigned n> struct F<0,n> { static inline unsigned func(unsigned val) { return val + n;} };
template<unsigned n> struct F<1,n> { static inline unsigned func(unsigned val) { return val - n; } };
template<unsigned n> struct F<2,n> { static inline unsigned func(unsigned val) { return val ^ n; } };
template<unsigned n> struct F<3,n> { static inline unsigned func(unsigned val) { return val * n; } };
template<unsigned n> struct F<4,n> { static inline unsigned func(unsigned val) { return (val << ( n %16)) + n*(n&0xff); } };
template<unsigned n> struct F<5,n> { static inline unsigned func(unsigned val) { return (val >> ( n %16)) + (n*(n&0xff) << 16); } };
template<unsigned n> struct F<6,n> { static inline unsigned func(unsigned val) { return val / (n|1) + val; } };
template<unsigned n> struct F<7,n> { static inline unsigned func(unsigned val) { return (val <<16) + (val>>16); } };

template<unsigned n> struct f { static inline unsigned func(unsigned val) { return F<n%8,n>::func(val); } };

typedef unsigned (*fPtr)(unsigned);

fPtr funcs[256];

template<unsigned n0,unsigned n1> inline void fAssign() { 
    if(n0==n1-1 || n0==n1) //||n0==n1 just to avoid compiler warning
        funcs[n0] = f<n0>::func;
    else {
        fAssign<n0,(n0 + n1)/2>();
        fAssign<(n0 + n1)/2,n1>();
    }
}

__forceinline unsigned funcSwitch(unsigned char type,unsigned val);//huge function elided

__declspec(noinline) unsigned doloop(unsigned val,unsigned start,unsigned end) {
    for(unsigned x=start;x<end;++x)
        val = funcs[x*37&0xff](val);
    return val;
}

__declspec(noinline) unsigned doloop2(unsigned val,unsigned start,unsigned end) {
    for(unsigned x=start;x<end;++x)
        val = funcSwitch(x*37&0xff,val);
    return val;
}
```

I verified that all function calls are inlined except those to `doloop`, `doloop2` and `funcs[?]` to ensure I'm not measuring odd compiler choices.
So, on this machine, with MSC 10, this (thoroughly artifical) benchmark shows that the huge-switch version is a third faster than the function-pointer lookup-based version.  PGO slowed both versions down; probably because they're too small to exhibit cache effects and the program is small enough to be fully inlined/optimized even without PGO.

Comment: So you *might* lose the small inefficiency of the indirect call, and you gain the huge inefficiency of hashing/binary searching/linear scanning the switch.

Comment: @Billy: Last time I checked, compilers are perfectly capable of converting switch/case into an assembler jump table.

Comment: @DeadMG: Okay, so you save a single pointer dereference, and pushing the instruction pointer to the stack, **if** it can be converted into a jump table, and **if** all of the operations can be inlined.

Comment: If your operations are trivial (as the OP says) a pointer dereference can be a _relatively_ big deal.

Comment: ++ Since a switch statement is a possibility, that means the table's contents are known at programmer-time, in which case they don't need to be in a programmer-coded table, and they don't even really need to be functions. They could just be coded in-line, but perhaps the compiler's in-lining could be just as good. In any case, the OP should inspect the assembly language and single-step it to be sure of getting the best machine code. That all assumes there's no I/O or other time-taker making all this irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, it's a weird scenario.  The OP hasn't clarified why he needs this, unfortunately - maybe it's some encoding thing with a specced distinction by case, but it's sure odd.

Answer (score 3):

A switch/case may be faster, as the compiler can make more specific optimizations, and there are other things like code locality compared to calling a function pointer. However, it's unlikely that you'll notice a substantial performance increase.

Comment: +1 for pointing out cache locality, which I did not consider.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to beat the lookup table based indirect call with any other method, including switch. Switch is going to take at best logarithmic time (well, it might hash to get constant time, but that'll likely be slower than logarithmic time with `int`s for most input sizes).

This is assuming your code looks like this:

```
typedef void (*myProc_t)();

myProc_t functionArray[255] = { ... };

void CallSomepin(unsigned char D)
{
    functionArray[D]();
}
```

If you're creating the array each time the function is called however, it might be a good idea to amortize the cost of the construction by doing the initialization of the function array once, rather than every time.

EDIT: That said, the best way to avoid the inefficiency of the indirect call is simply to not do it. Look at your code and see if there are places you can replace the indirect lookup based call with a direct call.

Comment: You can't know that.  It might; after all, that enables inlining which (since the functions are trivial) could matter a lot.  And once it's been inlined into a compiler-internal spagetti monster, further simplifications may become apparent to the compierl.

Comment: @Eamon: Any benefit you get from inlining is going to be lost to lookup time.

Comment: The array of functions is static and known at compile time. I asked the question since in my mind the whole could be done faster in assembler.

Comment: @user547616: How exactly would you expect it to be done faster in assembler? You've got 255 operations to choose from, and the indirect call causes the choice to be an array lookup plus an indirect call. A `switch` is going to be a binary search or hashtable lookup (if your compiler is good), or possibly a linear time scan (if your compiler stinks). You won't get any benefits from inlining here because you have branches before and after each snippet of code, and because no sane compiler is going to inline your entire 255 choice switch.

Comment: my code would be something like this: 
begin:
chooseD 
goto_var A[D]  
code F_0 
goto begin
code F_1
goto begin
code F_2
.....

where the first goto simply jumps to correct beginning code of function F_D. The array A stores possible offsets of each function. 
I would expect that switch/case are compliled in something like this!

Comment: @user547616: No. switch/case compiles into a jump table like that in assembler.

Comment: @Billy I agree that in general switch requires binary search or hashing. But if the number of cases is small, it would be better to resort to tabulation. Like the scheme I commented above.

Answer (score 1):

> There is a variable D ranging in [0,255], based on its value it calls the function whose pointer is stored in a array F (with 255 elements)

Warning, this will result in a buffer overflow if D has the value 255.

Comment: Yes it was a typo. Array F has  256 elements.